# Change WordPress Permalink for a plugin page

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I am using Age Verification WordPress plugin. It asks the users to submit their age to enter the website. It does everything fine but the URL of the page is too long and do not look professional.

You can check the page here - sun.idwtestrun.info

When you open the webpage you will be taken to a page to verify your age. The URL of that page is too long. I want to make it shorter. Is there anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate page for this porpuse. When user enters the site redirect user to this page and run the plugin. Url which user is to redirected on you could store in session. It is not necessary to store it as GET-parameter.

I hope it will be helpfull.